# Generate n coordinates via console input in Python

Tags: python

```
enter code here

ref = (x,y)

print(ref)
print(ref[0])
print(ref[1])

n = int(input("Enter the number of points in the race"))
points = [] 

for i in range(1,n+1):

    m =  int(input("Enter x coordinate for number {0}:"
         .format(i)))
    n =  int(input("Enter y coordinate for number {0}: "
         .format(i)))    
    k = (m,n)
    points.append(k)
    print(points)
```

So this is a code to get an number of coordinate points .
But there has to be a better way.
Can anyone suggest a more advanced style of getting this code

Comment: Please check your formatting before posting a question. It is unnecessarily hard to read code in plaintext.

Comment: Well, you can have them input both x and y on a single line, and then parse it yourself. And you don't have to ask for the number of points; just have them press "enter" to stop.  Reading input from the console is always tedious.  That's why I try to read input from a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will directly read the elements and put it into list using map and list functions.

// input: 2 3

ele_list = list(map(int, input("enter elements with space separated:").split()))

Output:
[2,3]

Comment: Instead of list is it possible to create a tuple

Comment: Yes. Instead of list() use tuple().